# Как из контроллера передать данные в директиву?

Tags: angularjs

Приветствую!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из контроллера передать данные в директиву, используя синтаксис `controller as`

Например:

```
angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('first', function () {
        this.somevar = 'Lorem';   // -> Эту переменную
    })
    .directive('one', function () {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function () {
            console.log(somevar); // <- Получить здесь
        }
    });
```

Comment: куча вариантов, начиная от передачи в разметке, и заканчивая получением с скопа

Comment: @Grundy, я был бы рад парочке вариантам или ссылке с оными)

Comment: например https://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/FHVD9/

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, мне нужно не отобразить, а передать для дальнейшего использования)

Comment: @Николай, ну так и используй этот scope.obj в пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные неявные зависимости - зло.
Это как глобальные переменные, только хуже.
Директива не должна никак зависеть от контроллера.
Её должно быть безболезненно просто перенести в другое место.

- **Вариант 1(так себе):** На каждую переменную из внешнего scope внутри директивы заводится значение по умолчанию. Получается что-то типа %ENV% окружения. Все данные доступны в любом месте, но внешний контроллер может переопределить часть из них.

```js
angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('first', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.somevar = 'Lorem';
    }])
    .directive('one', function() {
       var defaults = {
         somevar: 'Ipsum',
         othervar: 'Dolor'
       };
       
       return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope) {
          var params = {};
          Object.keys(defaults).forEach(key => 
              params[key] = scope[key] || defaults[key]
          );
          console.log(params.somevar, params.othervar) ;
        }
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="first as c">
  <div one></div>
</div>
```

- **Вариант 2:** Изолированный scope у директивы, вся значимая информация передаётся через атрибуты.

```js
angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('first',['$scope', function ($scope) {
        this.somevar = 'Lorem';  
    }])
    .directive('one', function() {
       return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {text: '='},
        link: function(scope) {
         console.log(scope.text) 
        }
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="first as c">
  <div one text="c.somevar"></div>
</div>
```

- **Вариант 3:** Для обмена данными используются сервисы.

```js
angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('first', ['dataProvider', function (data) {
      data.set('somevar', 'Lorem');
    }])
    .service('dataProvider', function() {
      var data = {};
      this.set = function(key, val){data[key] = val;};
      this.get = function(key) {return data[key];};
    })
    .directive('one', ['dataProvider', function(data) {
       return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function() {
         console.log(data.get('somevar')) 
        }
      };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="first as c">
  <div one></div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь пример для первого варианта, не пойму, что ты имеешь ввиду

Comment: Пару минут, третий вариант допишу)

Comment: @Grundy, Добавил пример для первого варианта

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо! Решил использовать сервис :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот например:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('one', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log(scope.somevar); // <- Получить здесь
        },
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.somevar = 'Lorem';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div one></div>
</div>
```

Ещё вариант:

```js
angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('first',['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.somevar = 'Lorem';  
    }])
    .directive('one', function() {
       return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log(scope.somevar)
        },
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="first">
  <div one></div>
</div>
```

И ещё 1 вариант

```js
angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('first',['$scope', function ($scope) {
        this.somevar = 'Lorem';  
    }])
    .directive('one', function() {
       return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'first',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
         console.log(ctrl.somevar) 
        }
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="first">
  <div one="somevar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: обрати внимание, что в вопросе речь идет про _controller as_ синтаксис, только поле в контроллере, а не напрямую в скопе

Comment: @Grundy, можно поподробней? =)

Comment: @Николай, если ты в контроллере сделаешь `this.somevar = 'Lorem';`, то в директиве ты ее не достанешь как просто `scope.somevar = 'Lorem';`

Comment: @Grundy, а это разве не смешивание синтаксисов? И насколько "плохо" так делать?

Comment: @Николай, не знаю что такое _смешивание синтаксисов_. Пример который я привел - просто работать не будет

Comment: А чем второй вариант отличается? вроде абсолютно одинаковые сниппеты

Comment: @Grundy, подрихтовал  для примера Николая  :)

Comment: @Grundy, другая версия ангуляра же, ну.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, там можно было и первый поменять просто. В примере Николая в контроллере поле в this Добавляется а не в скоп

Comment: @Grundy, да, добавил ещё 1 вариант

Comment: В последнем варианте контроллер инстанциируется один раз? Не уверен.(Уверен, 2)

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, плохой пример. vp_arth указал почему

Comment: @Grundy, дак можно использовать второй вариант? Он вроде как больше подходит?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, спасибо вам)

Comment: @Николай, не уверен какой из вариантов ты считаешь вторым :-) из трех примеров - первые два - абсолютно одинаковые. В третьем несколько экземпляров контроллера.

Comment: @Николай, пожалуйста )

Comment: @Grundy ну уже  vp_arth опередил меня :)